# Need to implement Deep Learning architecture quite similar to Siamese Network

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, siamese-network

I must implement this network:

[image]

Similar to a siamese network with a contrastive loss. My problem is `S1`/`F1`. The paper tells this:

> "`F1` and `S1` are neural networks that we use to learn the unit-normalized embeddings for the face and speech modalities, respectively. In Figure 1, we depict `F1` and `S1` in both training and testing routines. They are composed of 2D convolutional layers (purple), max-pooling layers (yellow), and fully connected layers (green). ReLU non-linearity is used between all layers. The last layer is a unit-normalization layer (blue). For both face and speech modalities, `F1` and `S1` return 250-dimensional unit-normalized embeddings".

My question is:

1. How can apply a 2D convolutional layer (purple) to input with shape `(number of videos, number of frames, features)`?
2. What is the last layer? Batch norm? `F.normalize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give an answer to your two questions without going too much into details:

1. If you're working with a CNN, you're most likely having spatial information in your input, that is your input is a two dimensional multi-channel tensor `(*, channels, height, width)`, not a feature vector `(*, features)`. You simply won't be able to apply a convolution on your input (at least a 2D conv), if you don't retain two-dimensionality.
2. The last layer is described as a "unit-normalization" layer. This is merely the operation of making the vector's norm unit (equal to *1*). You can do this by dividing the said vector by its norm.

Comment: Thanks you so much!